# Foreach through multidimensional array with dynamic/unknown dimensions

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array with `foreach` but sometimes there's 5 dimensions and sometimes there's 2, but I need to foreach every array. Here is an example:

```
array(16) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "1"
  ["name"]=>
  string(1) "Bob"
  ["job"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "software"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "plumber"
  }
  ["kids"]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "Jane"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "girl"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "Sam"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "boy"
      [2] => array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "123"
        [1]=>
        string(11) "Main Street"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you get the point.... but imagine if I had a dimension of 10 in the array. How can I dynamically loop through them and do `trim()` to each value in the whole array?

Here is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = trim($value);
}
```

but I need it to go deeper into an array **if** there is an array and perform trim to all values in my `$array`.

Comment: [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php): https://3v4l.org/cQSpi

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank u for that. can you set up a performance vs `foreach`? Performance is criitical in my application. Other sources say `foreach` is 10x faster

Comment: Internal functions are always faster then usercode (as run through c code), especially a recursive function which your need to make, as will need conditionals to check if its an array, which would call another func like is_array(). Perf for the above can be found https://3v4l.org/cQSpi/vld#output